# Drill hole size suggestion for this pass-through socket

Tags: pcb, through-hole, socket

I'm considering using this pass-through socket for a project. Since I'm newer at this, I was wondering what size through-hole would be best? This socket will solder in, so I understand that I can go bigger than the diameter in the spec and not have an issue. The question is, how much bigger? I have read on here that tighter is better.

Here is the part: https://www.mill-max.com/products/socket/834-XX-XXX-10-001000. Looks like the hole should be at least .043" in diameter, if I am reading it correctly. There is a slightly wider part that is .061" in diameter, but I cannot tell if that is meant to be in the hole or just flush with the board.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That surely depends on how much physical stress it should withstand and how good your pcb material is. The tighter the more stress it can withstand, but the more your pcb material is prone to break when inserting it with force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 0.043" region is the part that goes through the board, and then the 0.061" rim sits on top of the board.

Given that drill sizes tend to be metric, your 0.043" hole is 1.0922mm, so the next two metric sizes up would be 1.1mm or 1.2mm. Given that is the drill size and the holes will be plated, I would go for the larger of the two (1.2mm) to allow a tolerance for the drill sizes being smaller - though you can check your PCB manufacturers spec as they will usually tell you the hole tolerance.

In any case you want it to be narrower than 0.061" (1.54mm), so that means your drill hole should be no smaller than 1.1mm and no larger than 1.5mm.

The best advice is check what the manufacturing tolerance of your PCB manufacturer is and add this to 1.1mm to get your minimum size.

Answer (score 0):

Found this recently, which is directly from the manufacturer. It is on the product page. There are links to two PDFs: "Inches" and "Metric". Here's the metric one: https://www.mill-max.com/assets/pdfs/metric/063M.PDF

It recommends a 1.17mm diameter hole (1.2mm prior to plating).

Thank you Tom Carpenter! Your answer was very helpful as well :) I will stick to your rule of thumb if I am unsure if my CAD (Eagle) is showing me sizes prior to plating or not.

Comment: Eagle does not care about copper thickness. So, for holes and vias, you always define the drill size.